# why splice not working correctly in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to delete row from my list using `delete` button .I do like this

```
if (state.indexOf(action.payload) > -1) {
      console.log('iff----')
        state.splice(state.indexOf(action.payload), 1);
    }
          console.log(state)

     return state
```

but it is not deleting the row .here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/bpSGPLLoDZcofV4DYxPe?p=preview
Actually using add button I am generating the list of item and there is delete button I am trying to delete item from list using `delete button`
could you please tell me why it is not working ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Avoid using `Array#splice` when working with state in React or Redux. This mutates your state, which you never want to do. Instead, favour immutable methods like `Array#slice`. e.g.

```js
const index = state.indexOf(action.payload);

if (index === -1) {
  return state;
}

return [...state.slice(0, index), ...state.slice(index + 1)];
```

Answer (score 6):

The flaw of this approach is that in JavaScript, **objects and arrays are reference types**, so when we get an array, we actually get a pointer to the original array's object managed by react. If we then splice it, we already mutate the original data and whilst it does work without throwing an error, this is not really how we should do it, this can lead to unpredictable apps and is definitely a bad practice. A good practice is to create a copy of the  array before manipulating it and a simple way of doing this is by calling the slice method. Slice without arguments simply copies the full array and returns a new one which is then stored. And we can now safely edit this new one and then update to react state with our new array. let me give you and example:

We have an array like this `const arr=[1,2,3,4,5]`. This is original array.

As I told you before, we can do that like this:

```
const newVar=arr.slice();
newVar.splice(Index,1);
console.log(newVar);
```

**Or**

An alternative to this approach would be to use it a ES6 feature, it is the **Spread Operator**

Our prior code can be something like this:

```
const newVar=[...arr]
newVar.splice(Index,1);
console.log(newVar);
```

That's it. Good luck